# Construct a finite field of 16 elements and find a generator for its multiplicative group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Construct a finite field of 16 elements and find a generator for its multiplicative group. Find all generators of multiplicative group.

Very obvious Construction of a field with 16 elements according to me would be ${\mathbb{F_2}[x]}/{f(x)}$ where $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of order 4 in $\mathbb{F_2}[x]$. I took $f(x)=x^4+x+1$.Elements of the resulting field are
$\{0,1,x,x^2,x^3,1+x,1+x^2,1+x^3,x+x^2,x+x^3,x^2+x^3,x+x^2+x^3,1+x+x^2,1+x+x^3,1+x+x^3,1+x^2+x^3,1+x+x^2+x^3\}$.

Now, Question is to find a generator of its multiplicative group.

I have calculated by hand that $<x>$ is the whole multiplicative group. That was very obvious by intuition that $x$ generates. Now the question is what other elements generate that group.
I have tried for $x^2$, though i did not calculate whole group,with in few steps i found $x\in<x^2>$ so i concluded $x^2$ generates multiplicative group.

In case of $1+x$ , with in 4/5 steps i got multiplicative identity 1. So $1+x$ does not generate this group.

It would become a mess if i write by hand what subgroup would each element generate?

Is there any better way to find out what all elements generate the multiplicative group?

Comment: Hint: The group is cyclic of order $15$, so if you have one generator, you should be able to find all of them.

Comment: Also, if $\langle x\rangle$ generates the entire group then $x^4=x+1$ ought to generate the entire group, so I think you might have made an error somewhere.

Comment: Oh, yes. I guessed it, but some where i messed it up. Thank You.

Comment: You know that the multiplicative group is iso to $C_{15}$, so it suffices to check (by hand!!) that neither $x^3$ nor $x^5$ is equal to $1$. That's a lot quicker than going up to fifteen. You do generate the log table while doing that, so it didn't go to waste, if you did it that way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If $\langle x\rangle$ is the whole multiplicative group, it is isomorphic to $C_{15}$, so your generators will be $x^a$ for  all $a$ satisfying $\gcd(a,15)=1$.  There should be $\phi(15)=8$ such values.

Comment: :) I did not concentrate on case of $C_{15}$.. Thank You so much for this. I do not have reputation to up-vote this :P Sorry for that but thank you.