# How would I find the Field's elments generator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, coding-theory

Suppose we would construct a Field $F=GF(2^4)$ by using $f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. In this case the generator is $\alpha=x+1$. Why $\alpha$ here is equal to $x+1$ how would I find this?

Comment: what is $\alpha$ representing?

Comment: sorry I have edited my question alpha is the generator of the field's elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check that the order of $x+1$ is $15$. This will show that it is the generator.

The possible orders of any element in $\mathbb{F_{2^4}}$ is $1,3,5,15$. So now you should check which of these is the order of $x+1$. For example,
\begin{align*}
(x+1)^5 & = (x+1)(x+1)^4\\
& = (x+1)(x+1)^2(x+1)^2\\
& = (x+1)(x^2+1)^2 && ((a+b)^2 \equiv a^2+b^2 \text{ in } \mathbb{F_{2^4}})\\
& = (x+1)(x^4+1)\\
& = (x+1)(x^3+x^2+x) && (\because x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 \equiv 0 \text{ in } \mathbb{F_{2^4}})\\
&= x^4+x\\
& = x^3+x^2+1\\
& \neq 1.
\end{align*}
So the order of $x+1$ is NOT $5$. Similarly rule out that the order cannot be $1$ or $3$.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. But how I would know the generator$\alpha=x+1$. If the question was construct a field $F=GF(2^4)$ given $f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. Now how could you obtain $\alpha=x+1$

Comment: Any element in $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ is of the form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. This is where you have to try different elements of the field. There is no simple (polynomial time) algorithm to determine the generator. But once you have one generator then it will be easy to find all others because in your particular case the group we are dealing with is of order $15$ (cyclic). Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454115/construct-a-finite-field-of-16-elements-and-find-a-generator-for-its-multiplicat

Comment: that's mean no specific rule just trail and error and one could even try $x^2+1$ for example as a generator and check that it should satisfy the condition $(x^2+1)^5$ not equal to $1$

Comment: Yes to begin with it is trial and error (sort of) but please read my solution carefully you need to rule out the other possibilities: $(x^2+1)^1 \neq 1$ and $(x^2+1)^3 \neq 1$ As well before you can conclude that $15$ is the order and $x^2+1$ is another generator.

Comment: why $\alpha=x$ is not considered as a generator?

Comment: Regarding to your comment that $x^2+1$ is another generator but we I tried to list all the element by using $\alpha=x^2+1$ and the list will be:   $\alpha^0=(1+x^2)^0= 1000$, $\alpha^1=(1+x^2)^1= 1010$ , $\alpha^2=(1+x^2)^2=1+x^4=1+1+x+x^2+x^3=x+x^2+x^3=0111$, $\alpha^3=(1+x^2)^3= (x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2)=1+x^3+x^5$, no we got $x^5$ which has a degree higher than $f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ so can we say that $x^2+1$ is not a generator?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the concept of quotient fields. There are two things going on: one is $2 \equiv 0$ and the other is $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 \equiv 0$. So getting $x^5$ doesn't mean anything, you still need to reduce it using these equivalences. So $x^5=x.x^4=x(x^3+x^2+x+1)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x=1$. This shows that $x^5$ is $1$, hence the order of $x$ is $5$. This also shows that $x$ cannot be a generator.

Comment: In the case $\alpha=x^2+1$, we get $\alpha^3=1+x^3+x^5=1+x^3+1=x^3$. So now compute $\alpha^5=\alpha^3\alpha^2=x^3(x+x^2+x^3)=x^4+x^5+x^6=(x^3+x^2+x+1)+1+x=x^2+x^3 \neq 1$. Thus order of $\alpha$ is neither $3$ nor $5$, hence it must be $15$,

Comment: Many thanx for the clarifications this would help so much to get better understanding of Goppa Codes as I started to understand these basic things. Can I ask you that if you could recommend any reference contains examples to get better understanding of Finite Fields and Goppa codes? Again I would like to thank you so much for your answers

Comment: You are very welcome. I would recommend you to look into the book by Lidl and Niederreiter http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Finite-Fields-their-Applications/dp/0521460948/ref=la_B001HMRJRW_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1438881117&sr=1-3